# Could anyone provide a fastapi websocket endpoint which could connect with the example given for RTK Query streaming updates

Tags: websocket, fastapi, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to get my head around **RTK Query** as it applies to `websockets`. The example given is

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { createEntityAdapter, EntityState } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { isMessage } from './schemaValidators'

export type Channel = 'redux' | 'general'

export interface Message {
  id: number
  channel: Channel
  userName: string
  text: string
}

const messagesAdapter = createEntityAdapter<Message>()
export const api = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: '/' }),
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getMessages: build.query<EntityState<Message>, Channel>({
      query: (channel) => `messages/${channel}`,
      transformResponse(response: Message[]) {
        return messagesAdapter.addMany(
          messagesAdapter.getInitialState(),
          response
        )
      },
      async onCacheEntryAdded(
        arg,
        { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }
      ) {
        const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080')
        try {
          await cacheDataLoaded

          const listener = (event: MessageEvent) => {
            const data = JSON.parse(event.data)
            if (!isMessage(data) || data.channel !== arg) return

            updateCachedData((draft) => {
              messagesAdapter.upsertOne(draft, data)
            })
          }

          ws.addEventListener('message', listener)
        } catch {}
        await cacheEntryRemoved
        ws.close()
      },
    }),
  }),
})

export const { useGetMessagesQuery } = api
```

for the frontend. It looks as though the idea is to make a request to /messages/{channel} and on successful receipt and caching of these messages to connect to a websocket api. I'm struggling to create a fastapi app that connects with this example so I can figure out the workings. Does anyone have an example they might be willing to please share?